# How to access db config in a included PHP script?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm rewriting my application to make use of CodeIgniter. Currently I'm struggling with DB. I've configured databases in `config/databases.php` but have no idea how to access them in a scripts that are loaded in a traditional, non-MVC, way.
In a view `login.php` I have:

```
require_once("application/views/pages/include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("main");
   }
}
```

in a required `membersite_config.php` :

```
require_once("fg_membersite.php");
```

in `fg_membersite` `Login()` leads to `DBLogin()` which is  :

```
function DBLogin()
{
    $this->connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=".$this->db->database." user=".$this->db->username." password=".$this->db->password."");
```

I receive errors:
`Undefined property: FGMembersite::$db` and `Message: Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter is a MVC framework, so I'm afraid you have to folow that pattern.
Best way to do is rewrite your functions so that you can use it in a model.

Of course you can bypass it, but when you are rewriting your application, you better do it right.

Comment: I was afraid it is inevitable. So I've rewritten my app even more and moved `fg_membersite.php` to libraries, but still can't access DB from there. I've created a new [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429986/how-to-access-database-in-library-class) about this.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, it seems likely that the variables you call in this piece of code have another name/location (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
function DBLogin()
{
    $this->connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=".$this->db->database." user=".$this->db->username." password=".$this->db->password."");
```

Maybe instead of calling `$this->db->database` you need to call `$this->db['database']` or something. If you supply the rest of the source code from that class we might be able to further help you.