# How to access database in library class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm rewriting my application to make use of CodeIgniter. Currently I'm struggling with DB. I've configured databases in `config/databases.php` but have no idea how to access them at a library level.
I'm loading libraries via `autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'FGMembersite', 'phpmailer', 'formvalidator');
```

FGMembersite is a class which I'm using for registration and login.
I access this class in `login.php` view where I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($this->fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $this->fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("main");
   }
}
```

`fgmembersite->Login()` leads to:

```
public function DBLogin()
{

  $this->connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=".$this->db->database." user=".$this->ci->db->username." password=".$this->db->password."");
```

but `DBLogin()` here doesn't understand what is `db` . I receive errors like
`Undefined property: FGMembersite::$db` 
or
 
`Trying to get property of non-object`
How I'm supposed to access database config in my `FGMembersite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [CodeIgniter super object](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) to gain access to the auto loaded libraries, from within other libraries. Like so

```
$ci =& get_instance();

$this->connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=" . $ci->db->database . 
                               " user=" . $ci->db->username . 
                               " password=" . $ci->db->password );
```

It looks like you were trying to use this method in your code, except you only used it for the `username` field, not the `database` and `password` ones.

You can save the ci instance by assigning it to a class property in your classes constructor, like so:

```
class Yourclass {

    private $ci;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->ci =& get_instance();  

    }

    public DBLogin() {

         $this->connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=" .
                             $this->ci->db->database . 
                               " user=" . $this->ci->db->username . 
                               " password=" . $this->ci->db->password );
    }

    public somethingElse() {

        print_r ($this->ci->db->username);

    }

}
```

Comment: yes, I tried using `$ci` earlier, but must have made mistakes somewhere. anyway, it works now, however it doesn't appear to be perfect enough. how can I declare `$ci` outside the `DBLogin()` function, so I can use it in other functions as well?

Comment: You can assigned it to a property of your class (see updated answer), then use it with $this->ci->db->name.